# Stuck between ngRepeat, ngSrc, ngHref and JSON objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-href

I'm trying to set a simple ng-repeat but it doesn't work. I included `angularJS`, then two angular modules (`ngTouch` and `ngAnimate` because I need them for other purposes) and I included my Angular scripts files. I set the `ng-repeat` on a simple element that contains the `src` of an image and `href` of a link that should be taken from a `JSON` object from the `angular` script files. But the `ng-repeat` is transformed into a `HTML` comment.

index.html:

```
<div class="container-mini" data-ng-controller="graphicsController as portfolioGraphics">
    <div class="content coming-soon lang"></div>
    Flyers, posters, personal art, etc <br />
    <a data-ng-repeat="graphic in graphics" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-ng-href="img/graphics/{{graphic.href}}" title="my title">
        <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-ng-href="img/graphics/{{graphic.href}}" title="my title">
        <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt" />
    </a>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
app.controller('GraphicsController', function() {
    this.items = graphics;
});

var graphics = [
    {
        href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
    },
    {
        href: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
    },
    {
        href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
    }
];
```

Thanks =)

Edit : the link after my `ngRepeat` link is just for testing purposes (if it would work inside a normal link without `ngRepeat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5EJobuBS9DBvVSoPffQy?p=preview

html:

```
<div class="container-mini" data-ng-controller="GraphicsController">
    <div class="content coming-soon lang"></div>
    Flyers, posters, personal art, etc <br />
    <a data-ng-repeat="graphic in graphics" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-ng-href="img/graphics/{{graphic.href}}" title="my title">
        <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-ng-href="img/graphics/{{graphic.href}}" title="my title">
        <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt" />
    </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('GraphicsController', function($scope) {


$scope.graphics = [
    {
        href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
    },
    {
        href: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
    },
    {
        href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
        src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
    }
];

});
```

or

```
var graphics = [{
  href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
  src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
}, {
  href: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
  src: "brand-delices-flyer.jpg",
}, {
  href: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
  src: "brand-delices-carte.jpg",
}];


app.controller('GraphicsController', function($scope) {


    $scope.graphics = graphics ;
    });
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. It stills doesn't work. The ngRepeat is transformed into a HTML comment and the test link doesn't interpret what is between the brackets. Means it shows in Chrome console: <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt">

Comment: For this fix to work you will also need to change data-ng-controller="graphicsController as portfolioGraphics" to just data-ng-controller="graphicsController" or use portfolioGraphics to access your scope variables as mentioned below

Comment: thanks to you both. @sylwester, you forgot capital at the beginning of graphicsController in the HTML part. So if I understood well, either we don't put an alias for the controller and in the ng-repeat we can name it as we want (like here graphics), either if we gave an alias to the controller, it becomes accessible only with the main name followed by a dot and the element we want? (like here portfolioGraphics.items)?

Comment: You have it right - have a look at http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/ for some more detail about difference between $scope and 'Controller as'

Comment: Thanks glendaviesnz. I wanted to give your post a +1 because it's from there I understood the problem with the aliases but because I don't have yet 15 reputation I can't do anything... thanks a lot!!

Comment: @LightBen I can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sylwester gives you one fix, but if you want to keep the 'Controller as' syntax that you have used all of your scope variables are accessible via 'portfolioGraphics' so try

```
<a data-ng-repeat="graphic in portfolioGraphics.items" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" data-ng-href="img/graphics/{{graphic.href}}" title="my title">
    <img data-ng-src="img/graphics/thumbs/{{graphic.src}}" alt="my alt" />
</a>
```